# How to boot android without a screen

Tags: android

I want to transform an android phone to a device with special purpose. First I need to remove the LCD screen. But when I removed LCD, android failed to boot up. So, i need to boot android but without the screen.

I think to need fix the source code of android(init.rc maybe), But viewing this page: http://www.androidenea.com/2009/06/android-boot-process-from-power-on.html
now i have a doubt, the module responsible for check screen connection is not on the source code of android but on boot loader maybe, im not sure :(

Somebody knows where is the code that i need to fix for my purpose?   please... :D